# SUMPRODUCT difference between two dates for THIS WEEK entries only

Tags: excel

I have a column D containing all the Dates in DD/MM/YYYY format, and I would like to show the count of missed days for THIS WEEK values only from all the entries in column D.
In other words, if there is a difference between two Dates in column D and it occured this week, I would like to count it.

I have below formula to calculate "Total days missed" between first and the last entry in Dates column D, however I can't adopt this formula to display "Days Missed" for THIS WEEK only entries.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--ISNA(MATCH(ROW(INDIRECT(MIN($D$18:$D$500)&":"&MAX($D$18:$D$500)));$D$18:$D$500;0)))
```

Sample of data set.
[image]

Please help, thanks.

Comment: You do not show a data sample. (Always helpful).  Can the individual dates repeat? Or are they guaranteed to be entered only zero or one times?  Also, what version of Excel?

Comment: Yes, there can be multiple entries of one date. I am using Office 365 Excel.

Comment: I have updated the post with screenshot. Basically new dates will be added at the bottom of column D.

Comment: I have posted an Answer that should work for you.

Comment: There are no repeat dates in you sample data. Based on that the count of entries in a week should be 7 and any difference is missing. But to define the first and last dates of a week is onerous. If Monday is missing it should be Tuesday, or whatever next day, until Sunday or whatever day comes before if that is missing. That's the easy part. Next, consider if all dates are missing and that any formula will return a potentially wrong result for truncated weeks at the beginning or end of the list. No. I think you need VBA - and a much better grasp of the problem you are facing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For O365, in accord with your statement that there can be multiple entries of one date, I suggest the following (assuming your dates are **real** dates and not text strings that happen to look like dates):

**Total Missing Dates**

```
    =MAX($D$18:$D$500)- MIN($D$18:$D$500)+1-COUNT(UNIQUE($D$18:$D$500))
```

**Missing Dates THIS WEEK**  *obviously, you'll need to define the first and last dates of THIS WEEK*

```
    =7-COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE($D$18:$D$500),(UNIQUE($D$18:$D$500)>=wkStart)*(UNIQUE($D$18:$D$500)<=wkEnd)))
```

If your week starts on Monday, you can calculate:

```
wkStart: =TODAY()+1-WEEKDAY(TODAY()-1)
wkEnd:   =wkStart+6
```

More generally, to return a particular day of the week prior to `someDate` (or `wkStart`):

```
wkStart = someDate - WEEKDAY(someDate - DayOfWeek)
  where DayOfWeek is:  Sunday=1  Monday=2 , etc
```

So, making `someDate` = `TODAY()+1` ensures that if today is monday, it will return today and not the monday from a week ago.

HINT: It might be more convenient to define `wkStart` and `wkEnd` as a Named formula.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Your "Total Missing Dates" worked. What is the benefit of doing it your way? As for the "Missing Dates THIS WEEK" I don't think I know how to implement this. Can I define "THIS WEEK" using WEEKNUM(TODAY();2)? Week should start on Mondays... How otherwise can I determine current week's start and end dates for this formula? Last entry in Column D is also always the latest, which could help maybe determine "Missing Dates THIS WEEK"? But again I have no clue how to take this forward :/

Comment: @Omen For total dates, it uses fewer functions (which is generally more efficient) and avoids `INDIRECT` which is a volatile function. I'll edit my question with a method to compute `wkStart` and `wkEnd` now that you have revealed that you'd like `THIS WEEK` to start on Monday.

Comment: Thank you! With your dates formulas I managed to calculate properly Week start's: =MAX($D$6:$D$500)+1-WEEKDAY(MAX($D$6:$D$500)-1) and Week end's: =MAX($D$6:$D$500)+1-WEEKDAY(MAX($D$6:$D$500)-1)+6    However I still can't make your original formula to work. I filled your "Missing Dates THIS WEEK" formula and replaced Week start's and Week end's like above, that gives me =7-COUNT(FILTER(UNIQUE($D$6:$D$500);(UNIQUE($D$6:$D$500)>=MAX($D$6:$D$500)+1-WEEKDAY(MAX($D$6:$D$500)-1))*(UNIQUE($D$6:$D$500)<=MAX($D$6:$D$500)+1-WEEKDAY(MAX($D$6:$D$500)-1)+6)))

Comment: However during my test for the example last entry Date date 3/01/2021 the "Missed Days This Week" counter says 4. Where 3/01/2021 is Sunday and it should say 0. Another example of the logic I am tryin to achive. Today is Saturday 9/01/2021. I have entries in Date column for Monday/Wednesday and Saturday. "Missed Days This Week" counter should be: 3. As I have missed Tuesday/Thursday entries and Sunday is yet to come...  Can you help me update your Missing Dates THIS WEEK formula to reflect this logic?

Comment: @Omen Why are you replacing TODAY() with a range? I don't understand that. THIS WEEK is 28 Dec 2020 to 3 Jan 2021.  Mon to Sun, as you wrote.

Comment: Ron Rosenfeld I can see it now... rather than use TODAY() I was still pointing to the last Date entry in column D for no good reason. I think I am sleep deprived... Thank you so much for your help! It works :)